# How to disable a button by default, but then enable it with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a text field with a counter next to it. But beneath that is the submit form, and I want it to be inactive (grayed out, unable to submit) unless they have typed 100 characters.

I'm using a jsfiddle which I found on here and adapted to demonstrate what I'm doing:

http://jsfiddle.net/xqyWV/396/

Does not seem to be working exactly right. First of all, it's not grayed initially... but when I begin typing, it then recognizes that there aren't 100 characters and it does disable.

But, my code should re-enable the button if the length is not less than 100, i.e. when it reaches or exceeds 100 characters.  However, it does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#field").keyup(function() {
    el = $(this);
    $("#charNum").text(el.val().length);

    if(el.val().length < 100) {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled','true');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled','false');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this in your JS:

```
$('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and this in your HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="do some stuff" disabled="disabled" style="float:left;width:160px;height:30px;"/>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xqyWV/398/

Comment: @KellyCopley *does* have a good point though, when enabling use `true`, not `'true'`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your html you just need to add a disabled attribute to your submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="do some stuff" style="float:left;width:160px;height:30px;" disabled="disabled" />
```

In you javascript the main issue is that you are setting the disabled attribute to the string "true" or "false". Change it to a Boolean true and false and you'll be all set.

```
$("#field").keyup(function(){
    el = $(this);
    $("#charNum").text(el.val().length);

    if(el.val().length > 100){
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xqyWV/400/

Comment: "at least 101 characters"

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake here is the same answer **without** jQuery:

#### HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="do some stuff" disabled="disabled" style="float:left;width:160px;height:30px;"/>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/torug/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would just add an onclick:

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="do some stuff" style="float:left;width:160px;height:30px;"/>
```

and then in your `<script>` area, you can do:

```
document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute('onClick','functionname()');
```

By doing this you add an `onClick` so that the button can call a specific function.

By default the page will load it without an onClick. By adding the attribute you can the enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your **HTML**:

```
disabled="true"
```

... change it for this

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="submit"  disabled="true"  value="do some stuff" style="float:left;width:160px;height:30px;" />
```

and add this in your **JS**:

```
$('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```